# What is an Ordered Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an Ordered Word™.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Ordered Words™ | Not Ordered Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| CAT | DOG |
| BACK | FRONT |
| NO | YES |
| BEST | WORST |
| DEMON | ANGEL |
| FELL | ROSE |
| TEA | COFFEE |
| ONE | TWO |
| WOOF | MEOW |
| LIE | TRUTH |

CSV Version:

```
Ordered Words™,Not Ordered Words™
CAT,DOG
BACK,FRONT
NO,YES
BEST,WORST
DEMON,ANGEL
FELL,ROSE
TEA,COFFEE
ONE,TWO
WOOF,MEOW
LIE,TRUTH
```

**What is the rule?**
There are many more Ordered Words™

**Subtle Hint:**

> *Those born in 90's are more likely to know this rule.*

Comment: Looks like someone used this puzzle as inspiration for a [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136838/is-it-an-ordered-word). Nice! (FYI: The link to the question contains spoilers to this puzzle.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think an ordered word is one which

> Is created by pressing buttons on a phone keypad, in order of number size, in one direction.
>
>  To type the not ordered words, you need to increase the number size and then decrease, or vice-versa. *P.S.  - I was born in the 60's*

The relevant pattern is given by

> 2 → ABC
>  3 → DEF
>  4 → GHI
>  5 → JKL
>  6 → MNO
>  7 → PQRS
>  8 → TUV
>  9 → WXYZ

Comment: For best or tea you couldn't do this on keypad in one direction but would work if you just had 2-9 in one line

Comment: Thanks @BMS21 - I updated answer to clarify the order is in terms of number size.

Comment: @BMS21 unless you had a [Nokia 3650](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/Nokia_3650.jpg/1200px-Nokia_3650.jpg) :)

Comment: You forgot to say that the direction changes for each word in this model.  I.e. a word can be mapped on either increasing or decreasing ordinal value, but always consistently one of those.